# Configuring vsftpd for anonymous uploads to a single folder

Tags: ftp, upload, vsftpd

Im running a ftp server using vsftpd. this server is an anonymous public server with all the content on it only being able to be downloaded.

I want to create a new "uploads" folder, which would allow anonymous users to upload to. but i want them to only be able to upload to that specific folder and not to the other folders.

Is this possible? i have found the write permission in the vsftpd config file, but i havent find how to specify a specific directory

edit: i have made an uploads directory and made "ftp" the owner. the permissions are set to 777. I have also read the man page on the arch wiki but that didnt provide any solutions

Comment: You can add `anon_root=/path/to/ftp` your config to root only public users into a specific directory

Answer (score 0):

See the post
[Allow vsftpd user to upload only to a single directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/556117/allow-vsftpd-user-to-upload-only-to-a-single-directory):

> Then configure vsftpd properly for anonymous downloads and chroot()
> the anonymous FTP user to /var/ftp. It's been a while since I did
> that, but roughly and untested:
>
> ```
> # /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
> listen=YES
> #The following directives prevent local users from logging in and enables anonymous access respectively.
> local_enable=NO
> anonymous_enable=YES
> #The following directive enables write access to the ftp server’s filesystem. 
> write_enable=Yes
> anon_upload_enable=Yes
> # Sets the root directory for anonymous connections.
> anon_root=/var/ftp
> ```

See the linked post for more details.

Comment: I have looked at that post before but it doesnt seem to work. check the post edit for more info

Comment: Doesn't work how ? What error  ?

Comment: i get an error 550 in filezilla when i try to upload a file.

Comment: Error “550 Permission denied” means that you don’t have the necessary rights to execute this action. See the link for allocating the necessary permissions.

Comment: i have both write_enable and anon_upload allowed and the upload folder perms ar set to 700. i still cannot upload to any directory (including the upload directory)

Comment: Since I see you have used my answer. As my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by enabling "write_enable=YES" and "anon_upload_enable=YES", setting the permissions for the upload directory to 777